# how to solve the following recurrence? $t(n)=[4-t(n-1)]^{-1}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following recurrence :

$T_n=\frac{1}{4-T_{n-1}}$

I tried various methods using range transformation but still can't figure it out.

Comment: The *homographic transformation* $$T\mapsto\frac1{4-T}$$ has two fixed points $u$ and $v$, such that $u=1/(4-u)$ and $v=1/(4-v)$, whose values are $u,v=2\pm\sqrt3$ and such that $u=4-1/u$ and $v=4-1/v$. In such cases, it is a theorem that the reduced variable $$x_n=\frac{T_n-u}{T_n-v}$$ solves a much simpler recursion, here $$x_n=wx_{n-1}\qquad w=\frac{u}v$$ It follows that $x_n=w^nx_0$ for every $n$, that is, $$\frac{T_n-u}{T_n-v}=w^n\frac{T_0-u}{T_0-v}$$ that is, $$T_n=\frac{u^nv(T_0-u)-v^nu(T_0-v)}{u^n(T_0-u)-v^n(T_0-v)}$$ for every $n$ and $T_0$ such that the denominator is not zero. ...

Comment: ... If $T_0=0$, one gets $$T_n=\frac{uv^{n+1}-vu^{n+1}}{v^{n+1}-u^{n+1}}$$ hence $T_n$ is well defined for every $n\geqslant0$. Additionally the formula for $T_n$ shows that the values of $T_0$ such that the sequence is not fully defined are exactly $$T_0=\frac{u^{n+1}-v^{n+1}}{u^n-v^n}\qquad (n\geqslant1)$$

Answer (score 1):

If it has a limit $L$,
$T_n=\frac{1}{4-T_{n-1}}
$
becomes
$L=\frac{1}{4-L}
$
or
$L^2-4L+1 = 0$
so that
$L
=\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{16-4}}{2}
=2\pm\sqrt{3}
$.
Let
$L_1
=2+\sqrt{3}
$
and
$L_2
=2-\sqrt{3}
$.

If
$0 < T_{n-1} < 1$,
then
$\frac14 < T_n
< \frac13
$.
After this,
$\frac1{4-1/3}
< T_{n+1}
< \frac1{4-1/4}
$
or
$\frac{3}{13}
< T_{n+1}
< \frac{4}{15}
$.

If $0 < x < \frac14$,
then
$1+x
<\frac1{1-x}
< 1+2x
$,
so that,
if $0 < T_{n-1}
< 1$,
then
$T_n
=\frac{1}{4-T_{n-1}}
=\frac14\frac{1}{1-T_{n-1}/4}
\gt\frac14(1+T_{n-1}/4)
$
and
$T_n
=\frac14\frac{1}{1-T_{n-1}/4}
\lt\frac14(1+2T_{n-1}/4)
=\frac14+\frac{T_{n-1}}{8}
\lt \frac38
$.

Let
$u_n
= T_n-L_2
$.
Then
$u_n+L_2
=\dfrac1{4-(u_{n-1}+L_2)}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
1
&=(u_n+L_2)(4-L_2-u_{n-1})\\
&=u_n(4-L_2)-L_2u_{n-1}+L_2(4-L_2)\\
&=u_n(4-L_2)-L_2u_{n-1}+1
\qquad\text{since } L_2(4-L_2) = 1\\
\text{so}\\
u_n(4-L_2)
&=L_2u_{n-1}\\
\text{or}\\
u_n
&=\frac{L_2}{4-L_2}u_{n-1}\\
&=L_2^2u_{n-1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if
$0 < u_n < 1$,
$u_{n+k}
=L_2^{2k}u_n
$.

Since
$L_2^2
=\frac{7-4\sqrt{3}}{4}
\approx 0.07179676972449
$,
this converges
quickly.

We then have
$T_{n+k}-L_2
=L_2^{2k}(T_n-L_2)
$
or
$T_{n+k}
=L_2^{2k}(T_n-L_2)+L_2
$.

Therefore,
if $0 \le T_0 < 1$,
$T_{k}
=L_2^{2k}(T_0-L_2)+L_2
$.

In particular,
if $T_0 = 0$,
$T_{k}
=L_2-L_2^{2k+1}
$.

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$$4T_n-T_{n-1}T_n=1$$

Let $\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}=T_{n}$. So that $T_{n-1}=\frac{f(n-2)}{f(n-1)}$.

This gives,

$$4\frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)}-\frac{f(n-2)}{f(n)}=1$$

$$4f(n-1)-f(n-2)-f(n)=0$$

$$f(n-2)-4(n-1)+f(n)=0$$

This has characteristic equation,

$$r^2-4r+1=0$$

Whose solutions are $r=2 \pm \sqrt{3}$. Hence,

$$f(n)=c_1(2+\sqrt{3})^n+c_2(2-\sqrt{3})^n$$

$$T_{n}=\frac{c_1(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}+c_2(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}}{c_1(2+\sqrt{3})^n+c_2(2-\sqrt{3})^n}$$

The constants $c_1,c_2$ can be deduced by the initial condition.

Comment: How do you find the constants in that case ?

Comment: Given say $T_1$ you can get $T_2$. Then we plug the two values into the formula to get a linear system of equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$. @Zok

Comment: That's extremely complicated btw, given that T(0)= 0 * he forgot to mention *.
You will end up having an extremely long equation

Comment: everytime I try to solve 2 linear equations, I don't get an answer, it ends up having something like: c1( ...) = 0 which leads to c2 = 0 hence c1 =0 lol

Comment: Okay sir I'm waiting your answet habibi.

Comment: I see the issue with $f(0)=0$ division by $0$ occurs, neither $T_n$ nor $T_{n-1}$ can $0$ at any point or $0=1$. And so our formula does not necessarily work for that case.

Comment: So in that case it's impossible to define c1 and c2.

Comment: Then your solution isn't correct..?

Comment: It correct for $T_0 or T_1,... \neq 0$

Comment: But t(0) = 0 in the main question. That's the tricky point lol

Comment: How do you know @Zok

Comment: https://cerocks.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/fundamentals-of-algorithmics-brassard_ingles.pdf book page 145 ( 161 pdf ), problem 4.42 :)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2127093/closed-form-t-n-frac14-t-n-1-for-t-0-0 @Zok

Comment: in today's class the professor who made the book solved it. The answer will be the same formula u provided with c1=1, c2=-1.