# Closed form $T_n=\frac{1}{4-T_{n-1}}$ for $T_0=0$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I already showed [how to solve the following recurrence? $t(n)=[4-t(n-1)]^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124614/how-to-solve-the-following-recurrence-tn-4-tn-1-1) that for $T_0 \neq 0$ or $T_k \neq 0$ we have,

$$T_{n}=\frac{c_1(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}+c_2(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}}{c_1(2+\sqrt{3})^n+c_2(2-\sqrt{3})^n}$$

But this does not work for $T_0=0$ what should I do. I'm thinking taking the limit as $T_0 \to 0$ but not sure how to do it.

Comment: I wonder if your expression is for $T_{n-1}$ instead of $T_n$.

Comment: Just start from $T_1=\frac14$ instead of $T_0=0$; the method you linked to should work the same.

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. I think the problem is that if $T_1=\frac{1}{4}$ or even else then the recurrence can go trace back to a time where you divided by $0$. I plugged the recurrence into wolfram, It seems as if $T_k=0$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ the formula different. This seems pretty wierd to me. @GregMartin

Comment: If you redefine $c_1 \mapsto (2+\sqrt{3})c_1$ and $c_2 \mapsto (2-\sqrt{3})c_2$. You will see that my formula is the same as wolfram alphas, at least if we don't run into the problem that $T_s=0$ for some $s \in \mathbb{Z}$ @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve the following recurrence? $t(n)=[4-t(n-1)]^{-1}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124614/how-to-solve-the-following-recurrence-tn-4-tn-1-1)

Comment: The case $T_0=0$ is perfectly all right, see the page this one duplicates.

Comment: But there is a problem, when  you do the system the system of equations for the initial condition you get  $c_1=c_2=0$. And btw, the link you gave is my answer, I just have a question on when $T_0=0$ @Did

Comment: Let me suggest to read very carefully every part of the page linked. If you do, you might see that the case $T_0=0$ is fully solved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you can set $c_1=1$ always, since $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be scaled by the same number. Also set $\alpha=2+\sqrt3$ and $\beta=2-\sqrt3$. When I solve
$$
\frac{\alpha^{0-1}+c_2\beta^{0-1}}{\alpha^{0}+c_2\beta^{0}}=k
$$
for $c_2$, I get
$$
c_2 = \frac{\sqrt3+k-2}{\sqrt3+k+2}.
$$
So we can certainly try setting $c_2 = \frac{\sqrt3-2}{\sqrt3+2} = -\beta^2$ and see what happens. And sure enough, the formula
$$
T_n = \frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^2\beta^{n-1}}{\alpha^{n}-\beta^2\beta^{n}} = \frac{\alpha^{n-1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha^{n}-\beta^{n+2}}
$$
does seem to give the sequence accurately in the case $T_0=0$.

Comment: Do you know why I get $c_1,c_2=0$ when I try to make a system for it.

Comment: I really don't get why dividing by $c_2$ top and bottom clears the issue of $c_1=c_2=0$. And all other answers are unreadable to me. Can you please explain.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla Once again, *please read this*: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2124614/how-to-solve-the-following-recurrence-tn-4-tn-1-1#comment4375644_2124614

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer :-

Note that
$t(0)=0=0/1$

$t(1)=1/4$

$t(2)=4/15$

$t(3)=15/36$

Or, $t(1)=\frac{1}{4-0}$

$t(2)=\frac{1}{\frac{16}{4}-\frac{1}{4}}$

$t(3)=\frac{1}{\frac{60}{15}-\frac{4}{15}}$

...

So $t(n)=\frac{a_{n-1}}{an}=\frac{a_{n-1}}{4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}}$ with $a_{0}=0 \space and\space  a_{1}=1$

We have $a_{n}=4a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$ which is equivalent to $p(x)=x^2-4x+1$

We find that the roots of this equation are $2+\sqrt(3) \space and\space  2 - \sqrt(3)$

Let's say $r_{1}=2+\sqrt(3)$ and $r_{2}=2-\sqrt{3}$

So $a(n)=c_{1}(2+\sqrt{3})^n+c_{2}(2-\sqrt{3})^n$

For n=0, we get $c_{1}+c_{2}=0$

For n=1, we get $c_{2}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{3}}$

Hence,a(n)=$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2+\sqrt{3})^n-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2-\sqrt{3})^n$

So T(n)=$\frac{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2+\sqrt{3})^n-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}(2-\sqrt{3})^n}$

=$\frac{(2+\sqrt{3})^{n-1}-(2-\sqrt{3})^{n-1}}{(2+\sqrt{3})^n-(2-\sqrt{3})^n}$

Comment: You want $T(2)=1/4$. And $T(1)=0$. Otherwise it is good.

Comment: T(0)=0., I send you before the question number in the book

Comment: Yes but if you check $T(1)$ you see you get $0$according to your formula.

Comment: Then $T(2)=1/4$ according to your formula.